# How to prevent Chrome from automatically blocking audio capture

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chromium, getusermedia

I'm developing an extension that requires audio access.  Under normal circumstances, the user will choose either "Block" or "Allow", and that is fine.  Both actions will put the extension in the appropriate place in `settings/content/microphone`.  But while testing, I found if the user were to simply close out the Block/Allow popup by clicking on the "x" in the corner:

[image]

then I start to get `PermissionDeniedErrors` from `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia` (which makes sense).  But there are two big problems to this:

1. Chrome stops prompting the user if they want to block/allow - it just silently blocks it.
2. The blocked extension DOES NOT show up in `settings/content/microphone`.  So there is no way for the user to unblock it.

Then some time later (hours? days?), the prompt will come back.

I was digging in the Preferences file to see if maybe something about the extension is in there that wasn't getting surfaced to the UI, and I found this:

[image]

From this, I am guessing that Chrome is detecting the "dismissals", and just automatically begins blocking the setting for a period of time ("embargo days").

Is there *any* kind of action: either programmatic or user-based that can be taken to help direct users to unblock the extension?